# How to avoid zero (0) values when loading a CSV file into DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, csv, datagrid

I am working with an app where I load a CSV file into a DataGrid(WPF). What I didn't realize before I started is that it contains zero values which I don't really care about when it comes to displaying. How can I add a check to my code so it filters out the zero values?

```
//location of CSV File
        string CSVDataBase = @"C:\covid19_confirmed_global.csv";
```

```
//create collection for DataGrid source
        async Task<ICollection> CreateDataSource()
        {
            //create new DataTables and rows
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            DataRow dataRow;

            //create column headers
            dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Country/Region", typeof(string)));
            dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Province/State", typeof(string)));
            dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Number of Cases", typeof(string)));
            dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Confirmed Date", typeof(string)));

            //split lines at delimiter ','
            foreach (string Line in await File.ReadAllLinesAsync(CSVDataBase))
            {
                //create new row
                dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();

                //Country/Region
                dataRow[0] = Line.Split(',').ElementAt(1);

                //Province/State
                dataRow[1] = Line.Split(',').ElementAt(0);

                //Number of Cases
                dataRow[2] = Line.Split(',').ElementAt(2);

                //Confirmed Date 
                dataRow[3] = Line.Split(',').ElementAt(3);                

                //add the row created
                dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
            }

            //return dataview 
            DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
            return dataView;
        }
```

```
//button load CSV file
        private async void btnDisplayData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CovidInfoDataGrid.ItemsSource = await CreateDataSource();
        }
```

The first two columns in DataGrid are flipped because the first column in the CSV file is Province/State and the second column is Country/Region. In the DataGrid I want them to be the opposite.

I've added the CSV file for better understanding:
[CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0Tbh.png)

Sample with data besides the zeros:
[The same CSV file but with meaningful data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDVoW.png)

This is how it supposed to look like at the end:
[The required result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrfHq.png)

Comment: What do you mean by zero values? An empty line? or an empty cell? Or what exactly?

Comment: Btw, I'm not an expert in performance, but you split each row 4 times. Would be cheaper if you would split it only once into an array or so.

Comment: "Zero" means 0, not "null". As far as I can tell by going through the cells visually there are no empty "null" cells inside the "Number of Cases" columns.

Comment: The title of the question says "null" that's why I was confused.

Comment: It fixed the title. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I got you right but:

```
    string[] lines = await File.ReadAllLinesAsync(CSVDataBase);
    string[] dates = lines[0].Split(',');

    for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        string[] cells = lines[i].Split(',');
        for (int j = 2; j < cells.Length; j++)
        {
            if (cells[j] == "0")
            {
                continue;
            }
            dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
            dataRow[0] = cells[1];
            dataRow[1] = cells[0];
            dataRow[2] = cells[j];
            dataRow[3] = dates[j];
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }
    }
```

See if that works - it requires Linq though

Edited...
Ideally you would parse the date to a Date object and pass it then to the row as a date cell.
Furthermore, the order of the lines might not be as you indicated it in the screenshot, but once you have it in the dataTable, ordering according to a specific column should be easy.

Comment: Thanks, but It looks weird: https://bbcode0.com/full/2021/3/11/6389f7cc8116d5f1e24911f250c51484-full.png.html  
P.S. I had the AutoGenerateColumns="False" That was the problem.

Comment: What happens if you load only 3 or 4 lines?

Comment: This is what it's showing now: https://bbcode0.com/full/2021/3/11/39ceb2b3065851ae47bc9d70372f3fbe-full.png.html

Comment: Can you post a few lines of you CSV file?

Comment: It's in the original post on the bottom.

Comment: Yes, but all the lines visible in the image will get skipped, am I correct? So where are lines which you expect to display?

Comment: Maybe provide a sample of the data you have and a sample of how you expect it to look like

Comment: Here is the sample: https://bbcode0.com/full/2021/3/12/20cb3d80a2899a80a95d9a731fc68619-full.png.html

Comment: OK, and what should it look like? Because in the code snipped you posted, it will only take the first four columns, all the rest is neglected.

Comment: Added that to the initial post too.

Comment: Thanks, but: https://bbcode0.com/full/2021/3/12/e2e76c1597a0968955166ace43724a76-full.png.html

Comment: Sorry, forgot `await`

Comment: Yep, works now. The first two columns don't show anything, but that's probably because of the order switched. I''l take it from here. Thanks. (First occurrence of lines.Length is mistyped)